# How to remove all outputs ( PostgreSQL / Windows )

Tags: postgresql

I am using "-f" option to run a external SQL file(COPY command) as following, and want to remove the all outputs including strings which have *** as well.
Is there any way to do that?

```
psql.exe  -f temp.sql -p 5433 -U username -s postgres

***(Single step mode: verify command)*******************************************
COPY  TABLENAME FROM STDIN (DELIMITER('#'));
***(press return to proceed or enter x and return to cancel)********************
COPY 13
```

Any other PostgreSQL parameter to change the mode from "Single step mode" to other one?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On Windows, run `psql.exe ... > nul` to suppress any output

Comment: Yes. that would be great to eliminate every thing. BTW, is there any PostgreSQL parameter to change the mode from "Single step mode" to other one?

Comment: You turn on single step with `-s` and you turn it off by omitting it

Comment: I just found my mistake.. Yes you're right. My bad. Thank you so much.